# Autobean and XSS issue

Tags: java, json, gwt, xss, autobean

I have a `Spring` application on the backend and a `GWT` application on the frontend. 
When the user is logged in  ''index.jsp'' will output the user information as a javascript variable.

I am using `AutoBeanFactory` to encode and decode the user information as json.
Because the user can register and the user information are stored in the database I try to follow the [OWASP XSS Preventing cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) by escaping the user information in the JSP page.

I am using the esapi library to do the encoding. The server side code looks like this:

```
public static String serializeUserToJson(CustomUser user) {
        String json;
        AppUserProxy appUserProxy = appUserFactory.appuser().as();
        appUserProxy.setFirstname(encoder.encodeForHTML(user.getFirstname()));
        appUserProxy.setLastname(encoder.encodeForHTML(user.getLastname()));
        AutoBean<AppUserProxy> bean = appUserFactory.appuser(appUserProxy);
        json = AutoBeanCodex.encode(bean).getPayload();
        return json;
    }
```

I tried to use `encodeForHTML` and `encodeForJavaScript()`.
This works fine for normal characters however as soon as I use Umlaute characters (ü, ä, ö) I run into problems.

If I use the `encodeforHTML()` function the javascript variable looks like this (note firstname has an ü):

```
var data = {'user':'{"email":"john.doe&#x40;gmail.com","lastname":"Doe","firstname":"&Uuml;ber"}'};
```

Decoding with Autobean works fine however the character ü  is not displayed properly but the HTML escaped one (`&Uuml;ber`).

When I use the `encodeForJavaScript()` function the output is as follows:

```
var data = {'user':'{"email":"john.doe&#x40;gmail.com","lastname":"Doe","firstname":"\\xDCber"}'};
```

When I try to decode the JSON string I run into a weird problem. In Development Mode/Hosted Mode decoding works fine and the Umlaut is properly displayed. 
However as soon as I run the code in Production Mode I get an uncaught Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error parsing JSON: SyntaxError: Unexpected token x
{"email":"john.doe&#x40;gmail.com","lastname":"Doe","firstname":"\xDCber"}
    at Unknown.java_lang_RuntimeException_RuntimeException__Ljava_lang_String_2V(Unknown Source)
    at Unknown.java_lang_IllegalArgumentException_IllegalArgumentException__Ljava_lang_String_2V(Unknown Source)
    at Unknown.com_google_gwt_core_client_JsonUtils_throwIllegalArgumentException__Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_String_2V(Unknown Source)
    at Unknown.com_google_gwt_core_client_JsonUtils_safeEval__Ljava_lang_String_2Lcom_google_gwt_core_client_JavaScriptObject_2(Unknown Source)
    at Unknown.com_google_web_bindery_autobean_shared_impl_StringQuoter_split__Ljava_lang_String_2Lcom_google_web_bindery_autobean_shared_Splittable_2(Unknown Source)
    at Unknown.com_google_web_bindery_autobean_shared_AutoBeanCodex_decode__Lcom_google_web_bindery_autobean_shared_AutoBeanFactory_2Ljava_lang_Class_2Ljava_lang_String_2Lcom_google_web_bindery_autobean_shared_AutoBean_2(Unknown Source)
    at Unknown.com_gmi_nordborglab_browser_client_mvp_main_UserInfoPresenter_onBind__V(Unknown Source)
```

I can think of following solutions:

1. Rely only on input validation (when the data is stored in the db) and remove the output encoding. But that's not the recommended approach.
2. Replace the Umlaute with normal ASCII characters (ü => ue) and continue to use output encoding
3. use some library which escapes the XSS characters but leaves the Umlaute alone.

I am thankful for some feedback

**Update**: Based on Thomas suggestions I am now passing a `JsoSplittable` from JSNI and then passing this to the `AutoBeanCodex.decode` function. It works fine in Production Mode however in Hosted Mode I get following NPE:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.CompilingClassLoader$MyInstanceMethodOracle.findOriginalDeclaringClass(CompilingClassLoader.java:428)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.rewrite.WriteJsoImpl.isObjectMethod(WriteJsoImpl.java:307)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.rewrite.WriteJsoImpl.visitMethod(WriteJsoImpl.java:289)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.rewrite.WriteJsoImpl$ForJsoInterface.visitMethod(WriteJsoImpl.java:228)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.asm.ClassAdapter.visitMethod(ClassAdapter.java:115)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.rewrite.RewriteJsniMethods.visitMethod(RewriteJsniMethods.java:350)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:774)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:420)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.rewrite.HostedModeClassRewriter.rewrite(HostedModeClassRewriter.java:251)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.CompilingClassLoader.findClassBytes(CompilingClassLoader.java:1236)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.CompilingClassLoader.findClass(CompilingClassLoader.java:1059)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

The code which causes this exception is following:

```
private native final JsoSplittable getJsoUserdata() /*-{
    if (typeof $wnd.user   !== 'undefined')
        return $wnd.user;
    return null;
}-*/;

@Override
public JsoSplittable getUserdata() {
    JsoSplittable user = null;
    user = getJsoUserdata();
    if (user != null) {
       String payload = user.getPayload();
       Window.alert(payload);
    }
    return user;
}
```

Window.alert(payload) works fine in production mode. In Hosted mode when I step into `user.getPayload()`  I get a NPE in `findOriginalDeclaringClass` function of the `CompilingClassLoader.java`. It seems that `declaringClasses` is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't explicitly escape anything; AutoBeans do it for you already. Or rather, if you want to escape something, escape the output of AutoBean's `getPayload()`, not the innards.

Your problem is that AutoBeans uses native `JSON.parse()` when possible (for both performance and safety reasons) which, per spec, only supports `\uNNNN` kinds of escapes, and not the `\xHH` that `encodeForJavaScript` outputs. In other words, ESAPI would need an `encodeForJSON`.

Comment: Thanks Thomas for the response. 
I tried to use ``encodeForJavaScript()`` on the payload and it seems to work fine. Does it actually make sense to encode the payload when Autobean already does it for me for each field (security wise)?
BTW: http://www.wijsmullerbros.nl/content/gwt-hostpage-init-data-encoding

Comment: What I don't understand actually, is why you (and the linked article) use the AutoBean's payload as a string instead of an object literal. You' then return your object as a `com.google.web.bindery.autobean.gwt.client.impl.JsoSplittable` from a JSNI method (instead of `Dictionary`), and you wouldn't even need the `{user: }` wrapper: `var user = <%= autobeanPayload %>` and `native JsoSplittable getUser() /*-{ return $wnd.user; }-*/;`. As for your original question: I wouldn't use `encodeForJavaScript`, but you have to be careful then about your page encoding (should be UTF-8 already though)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I didn't think of that. I tried to return a Splittable directly and it works fine in Production Mode. However in Hosted Mode I get a NPE when I call ``Splittable.getPayload()`` (see my question for exception details).

Comment: You have to use `JsoSplittable` explicitly, otherwise (using `Splittable`) GWT cannot know whether it's supposed to be a `JsoSplittable` or `JsonSplittable`; and `JavaScriptObject`s (like `JsoSplittable`; aka _overlay types_) are really special beasts: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/OverlayTypes

Comment: I am actually using ``JsoSplittable`` but somehow I get an NPE when the GWT compiler rewrites the class for Hosted mode (to be honest I don't know enough about the internals of GWT, to know why it is doing it anyways). I updated my answer with some additional code and highlighted the call that causes this NPE. Could this be a bug in the gwt dev mode?

Comment: D'oh, it looks like it's not possible (or rather, not as easy): `JsoSplittable` is marked `@GwtScriptOnly` which makes it unusable in DevMode (and probably what causes the exception). I believed we did that in our app, but the guy who coded it actually called `JSON.stringify` (in JSNI) on the object before parsing it back using `AutoBeanCodex` :'(