# Regex to prevent XSS attack in json string

Tags: java, json, regex, owasp, esapi

I'm performing input validation in java using ESAPI.validator().getValidInput method call to prevent XSS attacks in POST requests.

I am sending my json string to this method to validate against a regex.

My ESAPI regex is as follows:

```
    Validator.SafeStringSpcCharacters=(?u)^[.\\p{Alnum}\\p{Space}*,()&+!@#$%^_={}:";'?~`|\\[\\]\\\\\/-]{0,2147483647}$
```

Please advice for a valid regex to prevent XSS attacks in json string.

Comment: Possible duplicate:. http://stackoverflow.com/q/31308968/557153

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Autobean and XSS issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428997/autobean-and-xss-issue)